# OTRS javascript crash after upgrade

Tags: javascript, caching, otrs

I upgraded OTRS from 3.2.9 to 3.3.4 following the steps. Everything went fine except the FAQ module or to be more specific the javascript for the FAQ.
When I press FAQ->Explorer or FAQ->Journal this error apears

> Core.UI.InitTableHead is not a function
>   (?)()@http://support.expert-m.net/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentFAQExplorer:730
>   Core.Apphttp://support.expert-m.net/otrs-web/js/js-                                 cache/CommonJS_88c68afe3a3fef9cca17337bf33acb27.js:1252
>   x.Callbacks/c@http://support.expert-m.net/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_88c68afe3a3fef9cca17337bf33acb27.js:2
>   x.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://support.expert-m.net/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_88c68afe3a3fef9cca17337bf33acb27.js:2
>   .ready@http://support.expert-m.net/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_88c68afe3a3fef9cca17337bf33acb27.js:2
>   q@http://support.expert-m.net/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_88c68afe3a3fef9cca17337bf33acb27.js:2

So this is the error. Its related to OTRS cache but how I can solve this error.
So far i tried to run again otrs.RebuildConfig.pl and otrs.DeleteCache.pl , nothing changes.
Maybe if I run installer.pm and do a fresh installation ?
Thank you !

Comment: Try to restore any configuration that you have changed for the FAQ. i.e go to the admin section -> Sysconfig and click restore on any configuration that is not the default value in the FAQ module (there should be a circular arrow icon next to ones you have modified). hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Actually I solved the problem by upgrading the FAQ module. I should start from there in the beginning.